How to make Colors Mixer in vba
The following link provides colors mixer in html.
https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_mixer.asp
I am looking for colors mixer code in vba.
Let me summarize what I want.
I will enter #FF0000 which is Red and enter #0000FF which is Blue into VBA. Then VBA will produce #8c0073 for me.
Please look at following picture in order to see which color I want to get.


You possible need to use RGB function to rebuild what you call color mixer. For example #66FF99 is RGB(102,255,153). Appart from that it is pretty unlcear what your issue is? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? [ask]

If you want to obtain the color #8C0073, you can simply use Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(140, 0, 115). The hexadecimal notation #8C0073 translates to RGB values as follows: 8C in hex equals 140 in decimal, 00 equals 0, and 73 equals 115. On the left side, the values are in hexadecimal, and on the right side, they are in decimal, which is what the RGB function requires.

It  would be best to edit the post accordingly. At least that you would like to get a value between to selected values was not clear for me based on the post. Not everyone will bother to read the comments.

Maybe the following function is of any help
Function GenerateGradient(color1 As String, color2 As String, steps As Integer) As String()
    Dim r1 As Long, g1 As Long, b1 As Long
    Dim r2 As Long, g2 As Long, b2 As Long
    Dim rStep As Double, gStep As Double, bStep As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
    Dim gradient() As String
    
    ' Convert color1 from hex to RGB
    r1 = CLng("&H" & Mid(color1, 2, 2))
    g1 = CLng("&H" & Mid(color1, 4, 2))
    b1 = CLng("&H" & Mid(color1, 6, 2))
    
    ' Convert color2 from hex to RGB
    r2 = CLng("&H" & Mid(color2, 2, 2))
    g2 = CLng("&H" & Mid(color2, 4, 2))
    b2 = CLng("&H" & Mid(color2, 6, 2))
    
    ' Calculate step increments
    rStep = (r2 - r1) / (steps - 1)
    gStep = (g2 - g1) / (steps - 1)
    bStep = (b2 - b1) / (steps - 1)
    
    ' Initialize the array to hold gradient values
    ReDim gradient(steps - 1)
    
    ' Generate the gradient
    For i = 0 To steps - 1
        r = r1 + rStep * i
        g = g1 + gStep * i
        b = b1 + bStep * i
        
        ' Convert RGB back to hex and store in the array
        gradient(i) = "#" & Right("00" & Hex(r), 2) & Right("00" & Hex(g), 2) & Right("00" & Hex(b), 2)
    Next i
    
    ' Return the gradient array
    GenerateGradient = gradient
End Function

You can test it like
Sub GetMiddleColor()
    Dim gradient() As String
    Dim middleColor As String
    
    ' Generate 21 colors between Red and Blue
    gradient = GenerateGradient("#FF0000", "#0000FF", 21)
    
    ' Get the middle color (11th in the 21-element array, index 9 or 10)
    middleColor = gradient(9)
    Debug.Print middleColor
    ' Output the middle color
    MsgBox "Middle color in the gradient is: " & middleColor  ' Expected output: #8C0073
End Sub

